# View Navigation using buttons in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to create a View with 2 buttons that redirect users to other views but nothing happens when they are clicked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<p>
    Please LogIn or Register
</p>

<p>
<button name="button" type="button"onclick="document.location.href=$('#logInUrl').attr('href')">LogIn</button>
<button name="button" type="button" onclick="document.location.href=$('#createAccountUrl').attr('href')">Register</button>
<a id="logInUrl" href="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("Account", "LogOn")) %>" style="display:none;"></a>
<a id="createAccountUrl" href="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("Account", "Register")) %>" style="display:none;"></a>
</p>
<% } %>
```

Working Code

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#button1').click(function () 
        {
        document.location.href = $('#logInUrl').attr('href');
        });

        $('#button2').click(function () 
        {
        document.location.href = $('#createAccountUrl').attr('href');
        });
    });

</script>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

<p>
    Please LogIn or Register
</p>

<p>
<button name="button1" type="button" id="button1">LogIn</button>
<button name="button2" type="button" id="button2">Register</button>
<a id="logInUrl" href="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")) %>" style="display:none;"></a>
<a id="createAccountUrl" href="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("Register", "Account")) %>" style="display:none;"></a>
</p>
<% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I doubt it's the problem, but you shouldn't use the same "name" for the two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using jquery, don't use onclick on the button but jquery click function of the buttons like

```
 $('#button1').click(function() {
       document.location.href=$('#logInUrl').attr('href');
 });
 $('#button2').click(function() {
       document.location.href=$('#createAccountUrl').attr('href');
 });



<button name="button" type="button" id="button1">LogIn</button>
<button name="button" type="button" id="button2">Register</button>
```

Comment: For some reason it has stopped working without making any changes to it. Any idea what caused it? I updated my Question with the code I am using now

Comment: First, you'd better ask in a new question since it will confuse its readers. Second, you have to put the click functions when DOM is ready which means placing those functions inside $(document).ready. Third, you don't want to put <script> tags inside of <body>. You should find a way to put that in <head>

Comment: I've used the $(document).ready (edited working solution) and it works again. Thanks once more Sheen. About the <head> section, my MVC views don't have one. Should I add them manually?